# Android - Basic question - link TextView to open new page (internal)

Tags: android

Probably a really basic answer to this but google is throwing up nonsense.

Ok, so i have a bunch of nested linear layouts, each one contains a textview and an imageview. What i want is my textview to be linked so that when a user clicks on the text, it will take the user to a new page that is in the same project. Not a website or anything.

Appreciate any help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, Juhani's right. You can use an onTouchListener. It's actually really simple. Just create a new .java file that loads the Layout you want in the onCreate. In the code you just use this line for the onClickListener:

```
            startActivity(new Intent(this, newjavafile.class));
```

and add the new Activity to your manifest. I had something close to this exact problem. The nice thing about doing it this way is the back button on the phone/device works to get you back to the main screen.

Comment: Thanks, will give this a go. Bounds to screw it up but we'll see.

Comment: Think i understand, i had some code that someone gave me and used your line to fix it, however i now get a force close when clicking on the link. Fixable i hope. Anyway thanks for this!

Comment: It should be something fairly simple to fix, I'd hope. That's the line of code I've always used. Watch your stack trace, it's really useful.

Answer (score 2):

You can add an onTouchListner to you TextViews and when user clicks on it you simply launch a new Activity. Google for adding touch listeners and then for launching activities and you will find the components you need.

Activities are like pages in Android apps.

Comment: Is that the best way to do it? I thought it would be pretty simple considering it's just linking some text.

Answer (score 1):

First write attribute in TextView Like,

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="Click Here" />
```

And in Java File

```
TextView text= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

        text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class));
            }
        });
```